ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'partio'. Library wirtten in C cant be seen by python
As part of my thesis I use a tool that need the partio library to manage particle vectors and i/o. Even if I follow the steps for building the code, python does not see it as a module and of course when i run scripts that have "import partio" i get back:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'partio'
The library is written in C and there is no pip directory to downloaded from.
If you can help me solve this I'll be very grateful because my thesis depends on this.
I tried both ways of installing according to the readme file and nothing works. Furthermore I tried pip instal . --use-pep-517 but was receiving the following error(only main point of the error).
Bellow you can find the full error I'm receiving with pip install:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Processing /home/dapt/Desktop/Thesis/partio
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: partio
Building wheel for partio (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Building wheel for partio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [76 lines of output]
WARNING setuptools_scm.pyproject_reading toml section missing 'pyproject.toml does not contain a tool.setuptools_scm section'
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
-- Checking for module 'glut'
--   No package 'glut' found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
Could NOT find Python (missing: Interpreter Development Development.Module
Development.Embed)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
/usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPython.cmake:561 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
CMakeLists.txt:124 (find_package)
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/home/dapt/Desktop/Thesis/partio/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310_partio/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  
  ==> Configuring:
  cmake -S /home/dapt/Desktop/Thesis/partio -B /home/dapt/Desktop/Thesis/partio/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310_partio -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DPARTIO_ORIGIN_RPATH=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=build/install -DPython_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.10  -DPython_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  -DPython_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3
  
  ==> Building:
  cmake --build /home/dapt/Desktop/Thesis/partio/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310_partio --config RelWithDebInfo
  
  ==> Installing:
  cmake --install /home/dapt/Desktop/Thesis/partio/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310_partio
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/dapt/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "/home/dapt/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/home/dapt/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t1g20wja/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 410, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t1g20wja/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 395, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t1g20wja/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
      super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t1g20wja/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 146, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t1g20wja/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 104, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t1g20wja/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 184, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t1g20wja/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 200, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t1g20wja/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t1g20wja/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 967, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t1g20wja/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t1g20wja/normal/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 368, in run
      self.run_command("build")
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t1g20wja/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t1g20wja/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 967, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t1g20wja/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t1g20wja/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 132, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t1g20wja/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t1g20wja/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 967, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t1g20wja/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "<string>", line 41, in run
    File "<string>", line 95, in build_extension
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '-S', '/home/dapt/Desktop/Thesis/partio', '-B', '/home/dapt/Desktop/Thesis/partio/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310_partio', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo', '-DPARTIO_ORIGIN_RPATH=ON', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=build/install', '-DPython_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.10 ', '-DPython_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu ', '-DPython_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 ']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for partio
Failed to build partio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for partio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
